# ComboBox implementation without "select" tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, combobox

Is there are any custom implementation of ComboBox element (i.e. drop-down list) without  tag? May be some div with CSS or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

you can try my code, only use html, css and jquery :

create html :

```
<div class='dropdown'>
    <b>My Dropdown</b> 
    <span>&#x25BC;</span>
</div>
<ul class='option'>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropdown 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropdown 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropdown 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

for complete code visit  : http://jsfiddle.net/g6jrt8ey/

Happy Coding.

Comment: If you place a div below it, that div will be pushed down.  Would be nice if it overlapped, like a select box dropdown does.